# React component does not load inside map loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I was building a react app and got stuck at this issue where my component does not load in the case of a loop. Below is my code for StoriesContainer.js and Story.js. As you will notice I am calling the Story component twice, the first call is outside the loop and that renders perfectly. However, my second call is inside the map loop and that does not seem to work. I am confused about what I might be doing wrong since I tried to look it up online and this was the correct way to do it.

If anyone can help that would be great. The image the result I get right now.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getStoryID } from "../services/api";
import { Story } from "./Story";

export const StoriesContainer = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getStoryID().then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      setData(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Story id={95666} />
      <h1>App.js</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.map((id) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-lone-blocks
          {
            console.log(id);
          }
          <Story key={id} id={id} />;
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
export const Story = ({ id }) => {
  
  return <h1>This is story {id}</h1>;
};
```

[image]

Comment: it's a typo, your map callback has no return statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning from your map callback.

```
  <ul>
    {data.map((id) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-lone-blocks
      {
        console.log(id);
      }
      return <Story key={id} id={id} />;
    })}
  </ul>
```

or simply

```
  <ul>
    {data.map((id) => <Story key={id} id={id} />}
  </ul>
```

Both will be fine and I will prefer the second one.

Comment: Wow. Cant believe it was that simple. A follow question: Why does a forEach not work and a map does?

Comment: forEach just loops over your array, it does not return anything, you can't, map returns an array, an array of story components, you can mark the question as answered if your problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

use the `return` keyword before `<Story>` in the map.